# ggplot: combining group in x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, multiple-columns, x-axis

I would like to create a bar plot with ggplot like attached excel image. It is qPCR data in biology. and the data looks like second image. Is it possible to make like images?

[image]

Thanks for your help!!

- ##### I edited my question and body. Please help again...

1. I made graph which attached 2nd image. And it is the code which i made graph

- 2nd image : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duxcx.jpg)

```
ggplot(data_AA,
            aes(x = Group, 
                y = pheno, fill = Group), 
            alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_col(data = data_AA_summary, color = "black") +
  geom_errorbar( aes(ymin = pheno-sd, ymax = pheno+sd), 
                 data = data_AA_summary, width = 0.2)+ 
  
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "black")+
  xlab(NULL) +
  ylab(paste0(colnames(Trait)[i]," mRNA expression")) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=13,
                      colour = "black",angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size=15,
                     colour = "black"),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=12,
                      colour = "black")
        )+
  stat_compare_means(method = "t.test", ref.group = "TGFbeta1", label = "p.signif", hide.ns = TRUE)
```

2. I added example data using table.

| Group1 | dose(uM) | ddCT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Control |  | 3 |
| Control |  | 3.2 |
| Control |  | 3.1 |
| Inducer |  | 7.3 |
| Inducer |  | 7.4 |
| Inducer |  | 7.2 |
| Comp1 | 5 | 5.5 |
| Comp1 | 5 | 5.4 |
| Comp1 | 5 | 5.6 |
| Comp1 | 10 | 4.8 |
| Comp1 | 10 | 4.6 |
| Comp1 | 10 | 4.7 |
| comp2 | 5 | 6.4 |
| comp2 | 5 | 6.2 |
| comp2 | 5 | 6.3 |
| comp2 | 10 | 6.4 |
| comp2 | 10 | 6.2 |
| comp2 | 10 | 6.3 |

3. I tried to make graph **data.frame**.
   If you know any helpful reference or introduction of function, please tell me.i will study..

Thanks again and sorry for unclear information..

Comment: short answer: yes. Please do not post data in the form of a screenshot, and include the data and what you already tried in the question.

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput`? So we can help you better.

Comment: @Quinten, I edited my questions and description. please check again! Thanks